# Is it possible to create a uitableview with 4 sections, but first section has no cells

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to create a section at the very top of my table but that section is only used for displaying special info that I don't want to place into a cell.  How would I do this without the table displaying an empty cell?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused: if it's not going to be a cell, what kind of UI control is it going to be? I assume that you know it's OK to build a special UI cell for the top section, and use it exclusively for the purpose of displaying that special information, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSInteger rows=0;
    switch (section) 

{   case 0:
        rows=0;
        break;

    case 1:
        rows=any number;
        break;
    case 2:
        rows=any number;
        break;
    case 3:
        rows=any number;
        break;
    default:
        break;
};
return rows;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 4;
}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Just return the special info as a section title in `tableView:titleForHeaderInSection:` and return 0 rows in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`. You can have a custom view for the header of that section by returning a header in `tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`

(OR)

You could just have a header for your table by assigning the `tableHeaderView` property to any UIView (or its subclass thereof). For more, check Apple's docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

U can use an empty cell in this particular section. The cell can be anything and transparent, too.